# Bad control character in string literal in JSON at position 40 Fresh installation Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, loader

I install fresh new Magento on my environment Magento version 2.4.6-p1 in the admin panel loader not gone it's take only loading.

[image]

can any one guide on the same.